# Accessing own ssh key generated in a Macbook

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I am trying to generate a ssh key pair to retrieve for my professor to load onto a server.

I have a Macbook Air (2015) and I followed instructions given online at siteground.com for Mac OS generation.

This is the code:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
vaRiOusLeTteRs
The key's randomart image is:
----Itookthisout
```

Now the issue is that when I try to access it this is what happens: I get a permission denied. How can I retrieve the .pub key to send it over?

(base) MacBook-Air-2:~ /Users/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-bash: /Users/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` should be enough to print the current logged in user public key. OR `cat /Users/<USERNAME>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` If none work, try using `sudo` before your command.

Comment: cat~/Users/Alessandra/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <- I tried this and I get no such file or directory

Comment: I tried with sudo, it prompts me for a password and then it says incorrect? I am pretty sure that's the correct password

Comment: I think you have generated the public key in the wrong place. If you see the line `Your identification has been saved in /Users/.ssh/id_rsa.` This should be instead created in your user director so `/Users/Alessandra/.ssh....`. Type `cd ~` and from there generate your key. So it will be saved in your current logged in user folder instead.

Comment: Hi, I have generated it in my directory now. The sudo command prompts me for a password but it keeps saying it's incorrect. I even generated a new key with a diff password to see what happens, but I still get incorrect password...

Comment: Ok I tried the cat Users/etc with the right directory and it prompted me the string to pass on. Thanks a lot for your help, I will close the question!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question was solved by qasimalbaqali, I will use this one as the accepted question since he only left comments. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept your answer when it prompts you to, to close it 'officially'.

Comment: Comments can be purged; please include *what* qasimalbaqali suggested that worked in the answer itself.

Comment: Ok will do now. Thanks chepner!